# How to split PDFs (with applescript)

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript

Does anyone know how to use the PDF kit thing to split pdfs in apple script, as i would like to split my pdf documents in to pairs of uncoloured and some colour pages.

I have tried pdftk, as i was orignally writing a bash script, but it fails on my document, which was produced from LaTeX.

Comment: PDF kit thing ? can you explain ? also how does pdftk fail ?

Comment: PDF kit (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html). pdftk doesn't give any useful information when it fails, just says:
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   LitRev.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.

Comment: I did try pdftk on another pdf, and it seemed to work fine. It just doesn't like this one.

Answer (score 2):

I'd look at installing Ghostscript via MacPorts or Fink.  Ghost script has pretty simple command line arguments for doing what you want.  You can then control it within an Applescript script.

Typically to split a pdf with ghostscript you do the following:

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dFirstPage=m -dLastPage=n -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf

Where m and n are page numbers.

You can merge pdfs with

gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=out.pdf *.pdf

Comment: that seems to give errors as well:
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
sfopen: gs_parse_file_name failed.
sfopen: gs_parse_file_name failed.
  ./base/gsicc_manage.c:709: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find lab.icc 
| ./psi/zusparam.c:819: set_lab_icc(): cannot find default lab icc profile

Comment: nope, that was because i left the - of infrount of dLastPage=3

Comment: Now it fails with many "**** Warning: Outline has invalid link that was discarded." and then 
Error: /rangecheck in 4
Operand stack:
   --dict:7/16(L)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   Color   --nostringval--   Rect   --nostringval--   Border   --nostringval--   --dict:8/17(L)--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   0

Comment: Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   4   1   3   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1   1   23   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--

Comment: Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1160/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:82/200(L)--   --dict:108/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:295/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:23/30(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
GPL Ghostscript 9.02: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Comment: Though the command works find for a different pdf that I tried. This one seems to open and be fine in preview though.

Comment: Probably it's just a bad file and for whatever reason Preview is able to handle the errors more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Automator has a "PDF to Images" choice which extracts all of the pages into individual pdf files... try that.

Comment: I would like to automate the whole process in one go rather than individual steps. I tried the "extract Even & odd pages" function, to split it into separate pages, but then it doesn't seem to hand the filenames to the "run apple script" utility.

Comment: If it doesn't hand the filenames, then you have to find another way. For example you could create an empty folder somewhere, have the pages extracted to that folder, then use the finder to get all of the files from that folder once the extraction is complete... then you'd have them to hand over to the next part of the code.

Comment: The problem with this would be if I wanted to make it into a service, then i would need to remember to only ever run it once at a time, as i don't think i can give it a different random temp folder each time